# fail to include sys/proc.h in Solaris 10

Tags: c++, c, gcc, solaris, solaris-10

Here is the same code:

```
#include <sys/proc.h>
int main(){
        return 0;
}
```

Here is the library:

```
ROHIT root@solaris-demo:/$ ls -ltr /usr/include/sys/proc.h
-rw-r--r--   1 root     bin        30063 Jan 11  2013 /usr/include/sys/proc.h
```

And here is the compilation result:

```
ROHIT root@solaris-demo:/var/tmp/$ gcc test.c 
In file included from test.c:1:
/usr/include/sys/proc.h:367: error: syntax error before "klgrpset_t"
```

Can anyone help me to know the reason behind this error and possible fix?

Here is additional information regarding my compiler and OS version:

```
ROHIT root@solaris-demo:/var/tmp/$ which gcc
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc
ROHIT root@solaris-demo:/var/tmp/$ 
ROHIT root@solaris-demo:/var/tmp/$ gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/sfw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.4.3/specs
Configured with: /builds/sfw10-gate/usr/src/cmd/gcc/gcc-3.4.3/configure --prefix=/usr/sfw --with-as=/usr/sfw/bin/gas --with-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --without-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-branch+sol_rpath)
ROHIT root@solaris-demo:/var/tmp/$ 
ROHIT root@solaris-demo:/var/tmp/$ uname -a
SunOS solaris-demo 5.10 Generic_147148-26 i86pc i386 i86pc
ROHIT root@solaris-demo:/var/tmp/$ 
ROHIT root@solaris-demo:/var/tmp/$ cat /etc/release
                    Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10x_u10wos_17b X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 23 August 2011
```

Comment: Try running `/usr/sfw/libexec/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.4.3/install-tools/mkheaders` maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention, the server is a production server and I don't think its safe to execute this. But I will try to execute in a test setup and get back to you.

Comment: Are you sure you want to include that? This looks very much like a kernel include that you're not supposed to include unless you're writing kernel code. Not all include files on your system are supposed to be included by you. Others might require other include files to be included before they can be included. Which manual page told you to include that?

Comment: There is a popular monitoring software "zabbix" which is failing to install on Solaris 10. "zabbix" includes this header. Please check [this](https://github.com/satterly/zabbix-stats/blob/master/include/sysinc.h#L210) and [this](https://github.com/prelegalwonder/zabbix/blob/master/src/libs/zbxsysinfo/solaris/proc.c#L36). This software works on Solaris 11. So, it means including `sys/proc.h` is valid.

Comment: @Dimitri: I have tried to run this mini program in a test VM of solaris 10. And it compiles fine. So, it means there is some issue with the gcc installed in my production server. Is it safe to run your command in production setup during live hours?

Comment: `mkheaders` is just supposed to rebuild some header files used by gcc.. I would think it's safe.. but I can't guarantee anything.  I don't think it would affect anything except gcc anyway, though.

Comment: @Dmitri: Thanks. Though this is not guaranteed, I could only dare to recommend System Admin during maintenance hours.